# Hibernate Criteria restriction by objects that are instances of the restriction class

Tags: hibernate, criteria

So if I'm creating a restriction for employees I'd say

```
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Employee.class);
```

So now I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to instead of doing this:

```
List<String> employeeIds;

Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Employee.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.in("id", employeeIds));
crit.createAlias("car", "car");
return crit.list();
```

To do this:

```
List<Employee> employees;

Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Employee.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.in("", employees));                //Doesn't work, but I think you get what I'm trying to do, query by objects themselves
crit.createAlias("car", "car");
return crit.list();
```

I'm trying to restrict a query for Employees by a list of employee objects.  Later I do a join with another table, so it's useful to restrict by a list of specific instances of the class that I'm creating a criteria for.

This would be the same as this sample SQL

```
SELECT * FROM employees
    JOIN cars
        ON cars.ownerName like employees.name
    WHERE employees.id in
        (<list of employee ids goes here>);
```

Answer (score 2):

The only idea I get to do what you what is to actually obtain a list of the ids you want to check. The Restrictions.in implies that you specify a property so "" will not work. Even though this is much more code than what you posted, I think this is the way to solve the question you posted:

```
List<Employee> employees; // This has to be the list o employees
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList();
Iterator it = employees.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
ids.add(((Employee)it.next()).getId());
}
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Employee.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.in("id", ids));
crit.add(Restriction.eq("car","car"));
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
     Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Employee.class, "employee");
     crit.add(Restrictions.in("employee", employees));
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried.  It ends up saying something along the lines of "unknown property employee of class Employee".  So it's not able to magically figure out that I'm interested in the ids.

This isn't really the end of the world so far, it just made one of my convenience wrapper classes not as useful as I thought.

Comment: I have always used the "id" property, so I have never run into your exact problem myself. I was curious if it would work. Thanks for letting me know.